# Script to copy files to multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script and it looks like it is asking for input when I am trying to copy files from one location to multiple windows servers.

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to execute the script without any interaction and it should copy the files from the source to the destination on multiple servers.

Point the script to the text file

```
$Computers = Read-Host "C:\File Copy\Source Server"
```

Sets the varible for the file location ei c:\temp\File.xxx

```
$Source = Read-Host "C:\File Copy\prod.csv"
```

Sets the varible for the file destination

```
$Destination = Read-Host "C:\File copy\Servers"
```

Displays the computer names on screen

```
Get-Content $Computers | foreach {Copy-Item $Source -Destination \\$_\c$\$Destination}
```

Comment: You don't need Read-Host. Not sure what you are trying to do on the last line though...

Answer (score 2):

`Read-Host` gets input from the console host. Simply remove those and set the variable equal to your path strings, if you don't want to be prompted.

Also your `$Computers` variable doesn't look like it points at a file with computer names to `Get-Content` from. Secondly your destination variable does not look like something that joins correctly with the UNC Path `\\$_\C$` I have updated the script to fix these two issues.

```
# Point the script to a text file with a list of computers
$Computers = "C:\File Copy\Source Server\ComputerList.txt"

# Sets the variable for the source file location
$Source = "C:\File Copy\prod.csv"

# Sets the variable for the file destination
$Destination = "File copy\Servers"  

# Get the content of $computers and copy Source to Destination
Get-Content $Computers | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $Source -Destination (Join-Path "\\$_\c`$\" $Destination)}
```

Comment: Might be worth using something like `"C:\File Copy\SourceServerList.txt"` in your example to make it obvious it's a file that's needed?

Comment: @JamesC. I agree, it's hard to know what was intended, but I have updated the script with what I think was intended

Comment: Do you not need an active PSSession with each of the "$Computers"?

Comment: @walksignison No, this script is copying files via smb to each the target's `C$` share which is accessible to administrators.